# What is the best way to do web scraping from an BlackBerry (10 OS) App?

Tags: mobile, web-scraping, blackberry-10

I am writing an BlackBerry app and I need to scrape about 50+ websites for data.
Does anyone know of any good client-side solutions that I can use ? I dont want to build a backend just for this.

Answer (score 0):

I actually wrote a [blog posting](http://blog.screen-scraper.com/2011/03/14/screen-scraping-for-iphone-andriod-blackberry-and-most-any-other-mobile-device/) about this a while back.  The example uses [screen-scraper](http://screen-scraper.com/technology.php), but the principles would apply regardless of what you decide to use for your scraping solution.  I deliberately wrote the posting to be relatively agnostic toward specific technologies, so it it will at least hopefully give you a few ideas.